# phpword, Header over complete Side, Content in Section

Tags: php, phpword

I'm trying to generate a `.docx` file with PHPWord.

All is fine but I want to set the header to 100% (over the complete white site), but the content must start with a margin on the left (2cm).

See below picture, that is what i want:

[image]

Has anybody any idea?

Comment: Where is your code? That is more important than the image.

Comment: i cant code that, in phpword i dont see this option to create how is the image